# Execute an npm-script (with variables) in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, npm-scripts

*Jenkins 2.107.3*

i have  a pipeline jenkins job to execute the script bellow with npm run

**the script**

```
{
  "name": "jenkins-postman-automation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test project",
  "directories": {
    "test": "01-TNR-CLIMPLUS-NEWMAN"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "api-tests": "newman run 01-TNR-NEWMAN/01-TNR-CORE.postman_collection.json -e 99-Environnements/${Environnement} "
  },
  "author": "Reda",
  "dependencies": {
    "newman": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

**Pipeline :**

```
node(){
  stage("testing"){
    deleteDir()

    echo 'git clone'
    git branch: 'master', url: 'git@git.ci/postman.git'
    sh "npm install"
    try {
      sh "npm run api-tests" 
    } catch (Exception err) {
      currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
    }
  }
}
```

### Two case :

1. **Case Success**:  when i declare `${Environnement}` like a job parameter
   [image]
2. **Case Failure**: is when i declare `${Environnement}` in the job `def Environnement = "DEV"` i have the error bellow :

> ```
> unable to read data from file "-e"
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '-e'
> ```

3. **My Question :**  i'd like to use a variable in my job inside the job, so how can i do it please help!

It only works when I use a declarative pipeline, but not now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `def Environnement = "DEV"` to `env.Environnement="DEV"`.  env.xxx will set value into environment variables of shell context, thus `npm run api-tests` can obtain the value from shell context.

Comment: thanks that works in a simple jenkins pipeline but no way with jenkins sharedlib any idea ?